# MountVolume.SetUp failed for volume "mongo" : hostPath type check failed: /mongo/data is not a directory

Tags: docker, kubernetes, rancher

I'm trying to configure a hostPath to launch Mongodb pod.

I have only one node of kubernetes v1.8.5 installed with rancher last stable version.

I have create folder `/mongo/data` and allow all permissions to all users.
[image]

I'm able to run docker image perfectly with docker without sudo:

`docker run --name some-mongo -v /mongo/data:/data/db mongo:3.2.1`

But when I launch to kubernetes:

`sudo kubectl create -f mongodb.yml`

I get `MountVolume.SetUp failed for volume "mongo" : hostPath type check failed: /mongo/data is not a directory`

This is the mongodb.yml:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: test-pd
spec:
  containers:
  - image: mongo:3.2.1
    name: test-container
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /data/db
      name: mongo
  volumes:
  - name: mongo
    hostPath:
      # directory location on host
      path: /mongo/data
      # this field is optional
      type: Directory
```

Any idea where I should looking for?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Removing `type: Directory` from the mongodb.yml works as expected

**Update:**

In new versions, changing `type: Directory` by `type: DirectoryOrCreate`, creates the directory.

Answer (score 27):

If by any chance you are using minikube, then don't forget that minikube itself is a container. So `hostPath` points to a path in that container, not to a path on your host machine. You have to mount your PC path into the minikube container and then into the POD.

Example:
`minikube start --mount --mount-string="/host/path:/minikubeContainer/path"`

Comment: Dude, thanks a ton! Just a note - minikube is VM, not a container.

Comment: @Skyblade Glad to help, also glad to learn something new! Do you mind expanding on the "minikube is VM"? I thought that if you are using Docker, then minikube is its container. E.g. you can do `docker ps` and see the minikube container running. Additionally, I had many problems when I was trying to free some disk space by cleaning `docker system prune`, and it deleted my stopped minikube container. I was completely confused, like where did my minikube instance go?! Maybe I am wrong though, how do you know it is a VM?

Comment: My bad. It was true in the past, but now minikube uses docker driver, so this is not true. Sorry for misleading you.

Answer (score 14):

Changing `type: Directory` to `type: DirectoryOrCreate` works for me.

Answer (score 4):

You are creating the docker container directly on the master node. As a result of this you could be able to run docker container with the newly created directory. But when you launch the kubernetes yaml file, it intends to run on a worker node. Since you create the directory on the master node, kubelet cannot find directory on worker node and failing. That's why "DirectoryorCreate" value on type flag is a kind of solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

I got the exact same error as you showed.

In my case, the issue was the folder defined in volume **hostPath** was not created. **Once the folder was created in the worker node server**, the issue was addressed.

Answer (score 0):

As a Windows Host, changing the format of the path from Windows-style `C:\Users\...` to Unix-style `/C/Users/...` worked for me.